# How to do file transforms / variable substitution with Visual Studio Online and .NET Desktop App

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Visual Studio Team Services Online (www.visualstudio.com) Release Definitions has a setting within `IIS Web App Deploy` to perform XML variable substitution.  Based on the in-line help:

> Variables defined in the Build or Release Definition will be matched against the 'key' or 'name' entries in the appSettings, applicationSettings, and connectionStrings sections of any config file and parameters.xml. Variable Substitution is run after config transforms.

Is there any such **simple** Task that can be applied when deploying .NET Desktop-oriented releases (for desktop apps or Windows services)?  Specifically, I want to replace the `value` part of key-value elements of `appSettings.config` files (or, post-build they are now `*.exe.config`).

I've seen some token replacement marketplace add-ons, but those don't do the trick.  They'll replace the `value` part of appSetting, but not based on `key`.  I could probably shoe-horn it, but its inelegant & fragile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @Rodrigo-werlang's answer, here's a more complete solution:

1) Create the XDT transformation file.  I followed one thread that had me editing the .csproj file to create `app.debug.config`, etc. but ultimately this isn't needed.  I created my file as `Release.config`, and used a `web.release.config` file as the basis of the transformations.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>
    <add key="MagicKey" value="#{MagicKey}#" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

2) In the Release definition, add a Task for [XDT Transformation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.xdttransform).  Apply the `Release.config` settings to the right `.exe.config` file.  **NOTE THE WORKING FOLDER** - It defaults to the source code directory, and I wanted to apply to the build artifact folder.

[image]

3) Add a Task for Tokenization.  I used Guillaume Rouchon's [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens), though I suspect any tokenizer will work fine.  Again note the working directory.
[image]

4) Set your release variables per normal.

Comment: Will do when the timer expires on it.  SO makes you wait 2 days before accepting.

Comment: Is there any tool which transforms multiple JSON files in the same way as XML transform do?

Answer (score 1):

You can add this two vsts extensions to do the job.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.xdttransform

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.utilitytasks
From this second you want to use tokenizer task.

Both of them are good documented so that you can implement it.

Comment: Thanks @Rodrigo - It took some more finessing (see my answer) but I got it eventually with your help!